# Adding child elements to a HorizontalStackLayout causes "A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI" error

Tags: xaml, maui

Im following allong the Youtube Series "Beyond Monkey" and on part 8, my XAML wont render at runtime (project compiles fine), hitting an error:

> A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI.

Ive literally copied and pasted the [code from the github repo](https://github.com/naweed/MauiTubePlayer/blob/main/src/MauiTubePlayer/Views/VideoDetailsPage.xaml) to check its correct, but it still doesn't like it. I've pulled out bits of XAML everywhere until it builds and it seems it doesn't like the icon XAML:

```
 <!-- Likes -->
 <HorizontalStackLayout
 Spacing="6"
 VerticalOptions="Center">
    
   <Image
    Source="imglike.png"
    WidthRequest="16"
    HeightRequest="16" />
    
    <Label
    Style="{StaticResource RegularLightText14}"
    Text="{Binding TheVideo.LikesCount, Mode=OneWay}" />
    
 </HorizontalStackLayout>
```

If I strip the image and label out of the Horizontal Stack Layout it works, but as soon as I try to add any content to them, app.g.i.cs blows up with an unhandled exception

> A cycle occurred while laying out the GUI.

> Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete.

The XAML looks ok to me and obviously works for the author, so I'm guessing is something unrelated that a XAML n00b like myself doesn't understand.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The XAML you've posted so far seems fine. However, without seeing any other code, it's nearly impossible to say what's wrong. Apparently, an unexpected layout cycle occurs, which means that something else is triggering it. Did you only copy and paste the code from the repository or did you actually download and run the code from the repository as well?

Comment: Which platform does this happen on?  There are several existing issues in the github repo regarding this error on Windows

Comment: ive been building along with the videos and they are working fine until now.
Yes, this is windows @Jason - is there a fix for the issue on windows as this seems like a massive MAUI bug surely? Or is it something in the wider code base thats causing it to fail on windows?

Comment: This seems to be related: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9075 It seems there is an issue with FlexLayout on Windows, indeed, like Jason wrote. In case that the FlexLayout isn't strictly required, maybe replace it with a different layout for the moment?  Which platform is the YouTube series using?

Comment: Just feeding back jason and ewerspej - changing to a different layout type worked. Changed from FlexLayout to horizontalstacklayout fixed it. Madness.
Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll mark it.
Cheers